# Setting up Xming to draw rootless Linux applications on my Windows desktop

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, putty

I have a Linux box, on which I'd like to run some programs, but controlled from a Windows box. I've managed to get FireFox running remotely by using the XLaunch program (via plink), but I noticed there's a Xmingrc file that allows me to create menu items for each program. Unfortunately, I can't figure out what the command string is meant to look like.

What would an entry look like to allow me to run FireFox rootless on my Windows desktop? For example, I'd right click on the little X, goto "Applications" and click "FireFox", and it would pop up rootless on my PC.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example from the [`xmingrc` manual](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/xmingrc.php):

```
Adding an oclock menu item to Xming's notification area icon
        MENU systray {
         "Analog Clock" EXEC oclock
         SEPARATOR
        }
        ROOTMENU systray
```

Here is another [example menu](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/my_Xmingrc) entry:

```
# Xming Server Resource File
TrayIcon ",101"
Menu putty {
    pageant exec "C:\Program Files\Portable PuTTY\pageant G:\PuTTY\private.ppk"
    separator
    chamonix execd "C:\Program Files\Portable PuTTY\putty -load chamonix"
    verbier execd "C:\Program Files\Portable PuTTY\putty -load verbier"
}
```